# Encoding special characters in wiremock response

Tags: java, wiremock

I am facing a scenario where the character "�" occasionally gets returned from my okhttp requests, and the character is causing some downstream issues. So I have added code to remove this character should it exist and I would like to add a test case to ensure this works correctly. The issue is that wiremock does not seem to like this special character.

Normally I would pull out the data from the response as so:

```
           String stringifiedResponse = response.getResponseString();

        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            custResp = response.getData();
```

Normally this works fine for all my requests. However, when I set up wiremock to return a response with the special character (even as a single one, and I would like to test with many different fields), the stringified response does have the response but the data is null.

This is how I have set up the mocks in my test class

```
    public static void mockCPInvalidChars(String ssn) {

    String customerPrefillPrimaryOwnerRequest = " {\n" +
            "  \"customers\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"partyId\": \"" + ssn + "\",\n" +
            "      \"idType\": \"LID\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}";

    String partyId =
            ssn.substring(0, 3) + "-"
                    + ssn.substring(3, 5) + "-"
                    + ssn.substring(5, 9);

    String customerPrefillPrimaryOwnerResponse = "{\"totalRecords\":1,\"customers\":[{\"partyId\":\"" + partyId + "\",\"idType\":\"LID\",\"sourceCode\":\"ICS\",\"firstName\":\"R�EEVES\",\"lastName\":\"WI�CKLIFF\",\"address1\":\"59 Ma�iling LANE\",\"address2\":\"ma�l2\",\"address3\":\"mail�3\",\"address4\":\"mai�l4\",\"city\":\"Mai�l\",\"state\":\"M�A\",\"zipCode\":\"010�10\",\"primaryPhone\":\"817504�0350\",\"alternatePhone\":\"81750�40351\",\"birthDate\":\"1902-0�2-10\",\"foreignIndicator\":\"N\",\"alternateAddress1\":\"88 LEG�AL LANE\",\"alternateAddress2\":\"leg�al2\",\"alternateAddress3\":\"lega�l3\",\"alternateAddress4\":\"lega�l4\",\"alternateCity\":\"LEG�AL\",\"alternateZipCode\":\"020�20\",\"alternateState\":\"L�A\",\"alternateForeignIndicator\":\"N\",\"mailTo\":\"\",\"alternateMailTo\":\"\",\"institutionId\":\"N\",\"taxId\":\"" + ssn + "\",\"taxIdIssuer\":\"S\"}]}";

    stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/my/url"))
            .withRequestBody(equalToJson(customerPrefillPrimaryOwnerRequest))
            .withHeader("Authorization", equalTo("Bearer " + OauthService.getOauthToken().orElse(new OauthToken()).getAccess_token()))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
                    .withHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(customerPrefillPrimaryOwnerResponse.length()))
                    .withBody(customerPrefillPrimaryOwnerResponse)));
}
```

Comment: I think your issue might be coming from not escaping the replacement character. Can you try replacing the replacement character with `\uFFFD`? I think any of these special characters will need their escaped JSON representations instead of their regular representation.

Comment: hmm interesting. The \uFFFD did actually generate the character for the stringified response. But still nothing comes through in the data. Something about the character seems to be breaking the mock.

Comment: EDIT: I was able to get it work using this method. Turns out in the String, I just had to double escape it. So  "NA\\uFFFDTHAN" and it successfully made it into the wiremock data. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your issue. I'm going to post my comment as an answer, and I'd appreciate it if you chose it as the correct response. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is coming from not escaping the replacement character.

� translates to `\uFFFD`, but you'll need to escape the escape character as well (silly JSON), so that becomes `\\uFFFD`, or in the middle of another string `"na\\uFFFDthan"`

Comment: works great, thank you. Additional note: \\uFFFD also works in the middle of a string.